# Two way data binding with ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I want to bind my `ng-grid` celltemplate to html textbox ( I am having ng-grid , which displays the data,below that I want to add a textbox, so that as I type something in textbox, the values should get update in cell Template of ng-grid).

Here is my html page:

```
<div ng-controller="bulkAssign" >

                    <form name="signup_form" method="POST">
                                <div style=" border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
                                        width: 1000px; 
                                        height: 200px;" ng-grid="gridUser">
                                </div>

                                <p><b>Editing grid</b></p>
                                <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" data-ng-click="testSeletion()"></div>
                                <label>Edit grid from textbox</label>
                                    <input type="number"  name="assignTo" ng-model="assignTo" placeholder="Assign order to"  class="form-control" >


                                </form>     
                                </div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'names',

        enableCellSelection: false,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        showSelectionCheckbox: true,

        multiSelect: true ,
        columnDefs: [
                     {
                         field: 'orderId', 
                         displayName: 'OrderId', 
                         enableCellEdit: false,
                         cellTemplate:'<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a ng-click="loadById(row)">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</a></div>' 

                    },
                    {field: 'trackingId', displayName: 'trackingId', enableCellEdit: false, cellTemplate:'<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><a ng-click="loadById(row)">{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</a></div>' },
                     {field: 'orderTitle', displayName: 'OrderTitle', enableCellEdit: false}, 
                     {field:'customerName', displayName:'CustomerName', enableCellEdit: false},
                     {field:'customerContactno', displayName:'ContactNo', enableCellEdit: false},


                     {field:'assignTo', displayName:'assignTo', enableCellEdit:true,cellTemplate:'<input type="number">'}
                     ],

                     selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,

                     filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions


    };
```

My question is after entering value in textbox, when i click button, is it possible to update values in ng-grid celltemplate?

Comment: What does this mean `<input type="number" {assignTo}>`

Comment: i was trying to bind text box value to that cell template now i removed it